# Using structs as arguments: Error: Struct not defined

Tags: c++, struct, g++

I am creating a class where I defined a Struct called "Room" which I declare as private in the header file. I have several public functions that require a "Room" as an argument. When I compile (in g++) I get an error saying:

```
Graph.h:42:17: error: "Room" has not been declared
```

Yet here lies the declaration (whole header file now):

```
#ifndef GRAPH_H
#define GRAPH_H


#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Graph {

public:


    // destructor
    ~Graph();

    // copy constructor
    Graph(const Graph &v);

     // assignment operator
     Graph & operator = (const Graph &v);

    //Create an empty graph with a potential
    //size of num rooms.
     Graph( int num );

        //Input the form:
    //int -- numRooms times
    //(myNumber north east south west) -- numRooms times.
    void input(istream & s);

    //outputs the graph as a visual layout
    void output(ostream & s) const;

    //Recursively searches for an exit path.
    void findPath( Room start );

    //Moves room N E S or W
    void move( Room &*room , String direction );

    //inputs the starting location.
    void inputStart( int start );

    //Searches the easyDelete array for the room with the
    //number "roomNumber" and returns a pointer to it.
    const Room * findRoom( int roomNumber );

private:

    struct Room
    {
        bool visted;
        int myNumber;

        Room *North;
        Room *East;
        Room *South;
        Room *West;
    };

    int numRooms;
    int _index;
    int _start;

    Room ** easyDelete;
    string * escapePath;

    Room * theWALL;
    Room * safety;
};

#endif
```

Are you not allowed to use structs defined inside the header file as arguments? If so, what's the workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: what the heck is the `private:` for?

Comment: this is not the full code, just a snippet. I can post the whole thing if you'd like. It's not small, though.

Comment: Can you please post the code where the compiler complains?  This might be a scoping issue; the real name of `Room` is `Graph::Room`.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone! I'm still working on all the little things like this:/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It compiles fine without the `private:` header. Why do you have this? Is the struct declared inside of a class?

**EDIT**

You have used `Room` before you declare it:

```
const Room * findRoom( int roomNumber );
```

Also, you can't return a `Room` object through the public method you have declared, since outside code won't know anything about it.

You need to predeclare it before using it:

```
class Graph {

public:

struct Room;

const Room * findRoom( int roomNumber );

struct Room
{
    bool visted;
    int myNumber;

    Graph::Room *North;
    Graph::Room *East;
    Graph::Room *South;
    Graph::Room *West;
};

Room room;
};

int main (){

  Graph x;

  return 0;
}
```

Or you could just move the second `private` up, above the `public` section.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a nested struct as an argument to a mthod of the containing class, then you must use the fully-qualified name such as `void outerclass::mymethod(outerclass::room);` Try that. You may need to make it public too.

Comment: `Room` declaration must be public, because it needs to be known to users of the public methods of graph. Try making it public and placing it above the Graph::Room declaration.

Answer (score 1):

1. Room cannot be private since you use it in your public member functions.
2. Either forward declare it like this :

   ```
   struct Room;
   // destructor
   ~Graph();
   ```
3. Or just declare and implement it before you use it at the top of the class.
4. `void move( Room &*room , String direction ); //this is not valid C++`

Comment: Yeah I changed that after the fact xD

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare any type before using it. A forward declaration suffices because you are defining `Graph::Room` in the same scope. However, since you have to define it anyway, I would suggest moving it up to some point before first using it.

Making `Room` private within `Graph` is perfectly legal (it is questionable if it is reasonable, though, if your public interface fumbles with it).

On a side note: Pointers to references are no valid types (references to pointers are!). Your `move` function is therefore invalid.